# ClipRRect doesn't clip it's child widget, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am clipping an image with ClipRRect, it initially worked, I changed nothing of consequence in the code and the image still displays, but the image no longer clips. This is the code, please tell me what is wrong.

```
ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              child: InkWell(
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage(
                      _images[index]['image'],
                    ),
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                  onTap: () =>
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, _images[index]['route'])),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me fine in [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev) try reinstalling your app

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);



  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              child: InkWell(
                  child:Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',fit: BoxFit.contain,),
                  onTap: () => null),
            ),
   
    );
  }
}
```

you can check this for more also
https://educity.app/flutter/how-to-clip-images-in-flutter

and mainly the problem is in BoxFit.contain **cahnge it to BoxFit.cover** cause that make the parent choose one of the dimensions which makes the other not clipped.

you can also try specifying image width and height this will work also ,
and finally you can try

```
 CircleAvatar( radius: 20, backgroundImage:NetworkImage('via.placeholder.com/140x100') )
```

Comment: I have tried reinstalling it many times, it refuses to clip, I have no idea why... Thanks for the help though

Comment: try to use my example ? change the image ? change your BoxFit.contain to BoxFit.cover ? and let me know if one of them worked

Comment: Changing the fit to BoxFit.cover does work, It's not the fit I need though. Is there any workaround?

Comment: try using 
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 20,
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/140x100')
)

Comment: also you can try specifying the width , height for your image

Comment: I realise the problem now, it's parent widget was choosing it's size, but putting wrapping it with a SizedBox widget will fix it, Thanks for the help

Comment: you are always welcome , so if that helped would you accept the answer and upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, It perfectly works for me

```
    ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      child: InkWell(
        child: Image.asset(
          _images[index]['image'],
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
         onTap: () =>
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, _images[index]['route'])),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

change fit: BoxFit.contain to cover:

```
ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              child: InkWell(
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage(
                      _images[index]['image'],
                    ),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  onTap: () =>
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, _images[index]['route'])),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where `ClipOval` and `CircleAvatar` was not clipping a image.

Pay attention to the final widget size (which is NOT obvious).

For instance, this code won't work when placed in the `actions` of an `AppBar`:

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: size,
  height: size,
  child: ClipOval(
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
    child: SizedBox(
      width: size,
      height: size,
      child: userProfile.photoURL.startsWith("http")
          ? CachedNetworkImage(
              userProfile.photoURL,
              width: iSize,
              height: iSize,
            )
          : Image.file(
              File(userProfile.photoURL),
              cacheWidth: siSize,
              cacheHeight: siSize,
              scale: mediaQuery.devicePixelRatio,
            ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

because the `AppBar` has 56 pixels high, the `SizedBox` will have 56 pixels high (no matter if you specify the `height`). To check this, insert all widgets inside a `Container(color: Colors.red)` and, if you see true widget size in red.

For the above example, you would need to remove the inner `SizedBox` (as is redundant) and insert all that tree inside a `Center`, so, no matter the available size, it will obey the `SizedBox` size and center the content.